# Send Emojis To My Text-area

Tags: javascript, php, html

How do I send emojis to the Text area when the user clicks on it ? I created a button that drops down and shows all the emojis when the user clicks on the button , but when the user clicks the emojis , how do I send them into the text area ?

home.php :

```
<a href="#">
<div class="dropdown" id="div1">
 <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Add emojis</button>
 <ul id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">

<img src="emojis\1f602.png" style="width:28px;height:28px;" />
<img src="emojis\1f603.png" style="width:28px;height:28px;" />

</ul>
</div>
</a>
```

Comment: Add myFunction to your question.

Comment: Why is it needed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use content editable div for this purpose.

```
<div contenteditable="true" placeholder="text status" id="content"></div>

<a href="#">
    <div class="dropdown" id="images">
        <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Add emojis</button>  <ul id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">

            <li><img src="image1.jpg" style="width:28px;height:28px;" /></li>
            <li><img src="image2.jpg" style="width:28px;height:28px;" /></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</a>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.x-git.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    jQuery('img').click(function(){ jQuery('#content').append('<img src="'+jQuery(this).attr('src')+'" width="10%"/>'); });
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
#content {
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    background-color: white;
    background-color: -moz-field;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0 black inset;  
    font: -moz-field;
    font: -webkit-small-control;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 2px 3px;
    width: 398px;
    max-height: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: But how will the user see the textbox ?

Comment: Need to use some CSS for that. See my updated answer. Both image and text can be added in content editable div.

Comment: The box shows but when I click the emojis so they could go to the box , nothing happens

Comment: `<div contenteditable="true" placeholder="text status" id="content"></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.x-git.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    jQuery('img').click(function(){
        jQuery('#content').append('<img src="'+jQuery(this).attr('src')+'" width="10%"/>');
    });
</script>

<a href="#">
<div class="dropdown" id="images">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Add emojis</button>
  <ul id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">`

Comment: Put scripts in the bottom. Also add <li> tags. See my updated answer.

Comment: still doesn't help and i tried a lot of different things

Comment: are you sure there is no way i can just send the emojis to the textarea ?

Comment: When I add the JavaScript code to the rest of my emojis code , it shows multiple emojis when I click one emoji